# R not returning true when object [sqrt 2 ^ 2 ] == 2

Tags: r, object, logical-operators

I know that running a simple line such as `sqrt(2) ^ 2 == 2` will return FALSE, but when I create an object with the left part of the equation, it returns the value 2, but when logically comparing the object to the number 2, I still get FALSE. This seems to be in error. Here is the code:

```
> (root.of.2 <- sqrt(2))
[1] 1.414214
> (root.of.2.sqrd <- sqrt(2) ^ 2)
[1] 2
> (root.of.2.sqrd == 2)
[1] FALSE
```

What’s going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look closer at your variable:

```
> print(root.of.2.sqrd,18)
[1] 2.0000000000000004
```

root.of.2.sqrd is numeric.

```
> as.integer(root.of.2.sqrd)==2
[1] TRUE
```

Read [FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f)

By the way, there are similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 1):

They are different numbers (sqrt(2) being irrational at some point of time some numerical inaccuracy, however small, will be introduced with it's rational approximation):

```
print(sprintf('%.20f', 2))
#[1] "2.00000000000000000000"
print(sprintf('%.20f', sqrt(2) ^ 2))
#[1] "2.00000000000000044409"
```